# HttpRequest Fails Unless I Use Chrome disable-web-security

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, httprequest, cors

I am making an httprequest to a third-party server ( http://remysharp.com/demo/cors.php ) where I have CORS properly enabled (at least according to http://client.cors-api.appspot.com ). This fails in all browsers except when I use disable-web-security in Chrome.  How do I overcome this so that it works without using disable-web-security?

Comment: Are you trying this from a `file://` URL? Can you show the code you're using to perform the request?

Answer (score 0):

If you using AJAX(javascript) to request third-party server ,it's response header should set:

```
Access-Control-Allow-Origin:*//or your domain
```

But if you can't set third-party server's response header like this,you can't making an http request by javascript